# Laravel - trying to echo a value from an array in a blade template. Works using php echo() but not blade syntax

Tags: laravel

I have an array that looks like:

```
$myArray = array(
           'firstRow' => array(
                0 => array(
                      'id' => 1
                      'title' => 'First Cat.'
                      ),
                1 => array(
                      'id' => 2
                      'title' => 'Second Cat.'
                      )
                    ),
           'SecondRow' => array(
                0 => array(
                      'id' => 3
                      'title' => 'Third Cat.'
                      ),
                1 => array(
                      'id' => 4
                      'title' => 'Fourth Cat.'
                      )
                    )
            );
```

This is being passed to my blade template. I can echo out values using raw php like:

```
<?php echo $myArray['firstRow'][0]['title'] ?>
```

Which works as expected. However, when I try to do what I thought was exactly the same thing using blade's syntax:

```
{{ $myArray['firstRow'][0]['title'] }}
```

I get the error:

> Trying to get property of non-object

?

Comment: The easiest way to find out what `$myArray` contains is `{{ dd($myArray) }}` and make sure how that array is constructed, as array or object ?

Comment: a var_dump confirms it is an array. Regardless, I don't understand why echoing it using the native php echo() function would work while using blade syntax fails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK.. I just solved this. Stupid. Sorry and thanks to the other commenters here.

The problem was that I had come code underneath this line which was commented out using HTML comments, ie <-- --> But it also contained blade syntax which of course is PHP and so is still firing. I would normally have noticed but due to my GUI not highlighting blade syntax it went unnoticed.

Comment: Out of interest what IDE do you use? I've been using a blade syntax highlighter plugin for Sublime 2, it's been invaluable.

Comment: Good advice, Adam, thanks. I'm using ST3. I'm sure there is a highlighter available, I'll look into it.

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid you are suspecting of the wrong line of code, because:

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

Is to something being used not as an array, but as an object:

```
{{ $myArray->firstRow->get(0)->title }}
```

So, your error is not exactly in this line.

But can be sure by getting the generated view source code in `app/storage/views`.

Comment: I'm sure it is this line of code, because removing it makes the difference between the page loading properly and throwing an error

Comment: Your line of code might be causing this, yeah, but it's not the exact source of your error, because it's an array. And we are not looking at the whole code here. That's why I asked you to look closely to your view source code, it might show you better where the problem is.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't get it! If <?php echo($myArray['some_key']); ?> is exactly the same as {{$myArray['some_key'])}} then, regardless of whether it is an array or an object, why would the former work but the latter fail?

Comment: They are the same and they should not be giving you an error, unless your array doesn't have `some_key`, but I'm sure it will NEVER give you an `object` error message. So, again, your problem might be causing by it (I don't know how!), but it's not in that particular line.

Comment: If you need more help you'll have to show us a lot more code and your full error message stack.

Comment: Hi, Carlos- I just solved this- see above. Thanks for your input. +1 for app/storage/views which I didn't know about, and which steered me in the right direction!